# How to impute specific row value by adding values of 2 different row values of same column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-wrangling

I have a DataFrame shown below:

```
 df = {'col1': {0: 'v1',
  1: 'v2',
  2: 'v3',
  3: 'v4'},
 'col2': {0: np.nan,
  1: 13,
  2: 76,
  3: 2},
 'col3': {0: np.nan,
  1: 91,
  2: 3,
  3: 33},
 'col4': {0: np.nan,
  1: 9,
  2: 47,
  3: 62}}
```

I want to replace all "nan" values associated with "Val1" of col1 by adding values associated to "val2" and "val4" and impute it in col2,col3 and col4.

So expected output will look like this -

```
  |    col1  col2   col3  col4
---------------------------------------
0 |   "v1"  15    124    71
1 |   "v2"  13    91     9
2 |   "v3"  76    3      47
3 |   "v4"  2     33     62
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc)

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'v1', 1: 'v2', 2: 'v3', 3: 'v4'},
                   'col2': {0: np.nan, 1: 13, 2: 76, 3: 2},
                   'col3': {0: np.nan, 1: 91, 2: 3, 3: 33},
                   'col4': {0: np.nan, 1: 9, 2: 47, 3: 62}})

value_cols = ['col2', 'col3', 'col4']

# Sum and Assign Data
df.loc[df.col1.eq("v1"), value_cols] = \
    df.loc[df.col1.eq('v2') | df.col1.eq('v4'), value_cols].sum().values

# Fix Types
df[value_cols] = df[value_cols].astype(int)
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   v1    15   124    71
1   v2    13    91     9
2   v3    76     3    47
3   v4     2    33    62
```

Comment: It gave me an error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bool' and 'float'

Comment: Instead of a text block can you run `df.to_dict()` and edit your question to include a portion of your dataframe as _code_ that can be used to replicate that error?

Comment: I have edited the question as requested,see if it helps!

Comment: After changing the col1 names from val1 to v1 it still works on Pandas 1.2.4.